# Android 9 patch images used for

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am having an question regarding 9-patch images in android.

**Do we use these 9-patch images only for background purpose or we have some other use of these 9 patches.**

I found we use these images in buttons background.

Can anyone suggest excluding buttons where i can use these images.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use it also when drawing custom views

Comment: In my case its working in background only.

Comment: any Drawable has draw(Canvas) method which you can use on your onDraw method

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9-patch images anywhere as long as it fits your layout purpose. For me, I use 9-patch if i found that the image can "repeat itself somewhere inside".

I use it as divider between two views, view backgrounds, or simply an image itself since I can specify which part it should extend.

Comment: You also means it will be in background.

Answer (score 0):

We can use specially for multiple screen which is adjustable in any screen size of device.

Here is site to create the 9-patch images.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: Thanks Sunil ,this site i know, i created many images . my question is little bit different.

Comment: okay you can use any where in your layout for any purpose it will adjust with screen dimension

Answer (score 0):

I use *9-patches* to set the background of ANY view doesn't have a fixed weight/height; usually, because of its content has variable size (i.e. it contains a `TextView` with variable number of lines)

This applies to any kind of view, custom dialogs, buttons, ...